# Build dependency with a specific profile

Tags: web, maven-3, netbeans-platform

I have a web project with a dependency I want to compile on a different profile so it generates some additional files I want on the web project.

To be more specific, a Web project with a Netbeans Application as dependency. The Netbeans project has a deployment profile that created the update center (just a folder with files in it). I want this update center to be added to the war file for deployment.

Is there a way to make the web project build the dependency on this profile so I get the files I need?

Is there other options to make this work?

**Update:** Example

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- The Basics -->
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>project-of-interest</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-id</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>resource2</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

project-of-interest has a deployment profile in which the files I need are generated and somehow resource2 points to the location of those files.

My main issue is making sure the files I need are available.

Comment: Can you show an example pom file to understand what you like to achieve?

Comment: Updated with some details as you requested, hope that answers your question.

Comment: The project-of-interest is a dependency not a plugin? Misunderstanding ?

Comment: Yes, it's a project dependency.

Answer (score 1):

you can point to specific profile with maven command

```
mvn clean install -P $profile
```